# How would a reduction from Vertex-cover to Feedback Arc Set work?

Tags: graph-theory

Karp’s famous paper on NP-completeness ([link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-2001-2_9)) gives a scant three lines to the reduction:

NODE COVER $\propto$ FEEDBACK ARC SET

$
V = N' \times \{0, 1\} \\ E = \{\langle \langle u, 0\rangle,\langle u,1\rangle \rangle \thinspace| \thinspace u \in N'\} \thinspace \cup \thinspace \{\langle \langle u, 1\rangle,\langle v,0\rangle \rangle \thinspace| \thinspace \{ u, v \} \in A'\} \\ k=l
$

How would it work?

Answer (score 1):

Take an edge $uv$ of the Vertex-cover instance.  Notice that in the construction you describe, the four vertices corresponding to $u$ and $v$ form a directed cycle.  Thus for your Feedback arc set, you have to choose one arc of this $4$-cycle to remove.  Try to establish the correspondence between choosing an arc of the $uv$ cycle with choosing one of $u$ or $v$ for the vertex cover.